# Crash after update to 11.10, from 11.04

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, upgrade

I have searched quite a lot, but it seems that I am the only unfortunate.

Last night I chose to upgrade (via Internet install) to 11.10 from my 11.04, but after the upgrade, Ubuntu just doesn't boot.

I was expecting some glitches, but never expected a complete crash.

My only fault, I left it to upgrade over the night, unattended, and went to sleep. Not knowing what might have happened.

I am attaching a screenshot, which might help knowing what's going on.  .
(Since I couldn't use system's internal imaging system as no OS was booted, I shot it from my phone's camera. I hope it's clear enough to read. please let me know if you need more details.)

[image]

Is there any way out?

**UPDATE**

As per instructions, I went to tty2, and ran `sudo apt-get update` which showed following errors:

[image: after update]

I then ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` and saw it processing many files. after a while when it quit, I restarted the system, but its still stuck at 'checking battery state'

`sudo apt-get update` still shows these errors, but `upgrade` says the system is upgraded `0 files to remove, 0 to change`

Comment: Is the network cable plugged in? Looks like it can't fetch things from the archive

Comment: Darn! This one was on a WiFi connection, so it wouldn't have picked the network connection (surprised, because at a point Windows 8 installer did) So I'll try the same on my home computer where I have a wired connection

Comment: Depending on the wireless card it might need a wired connection, but that would be your best bet.

Comment: Yes, @JorgeCastro. You're right. I realized this very thing. My home computer did just fine with a wired connection and is now working perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your computer has more or less finished booting, but there's no display.

### Likely solution

Try hitting <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> if your keyboard has media keys). Do you get a login prompt? If so, enter your username and password, plug in an ethernet cable if possible, then enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Chances are this command will fail, and recommend a command to fix broken packages. Try that command, and then reboot with

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

### Possible solution

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> after turning your computer on. You'll be presented a program called GRUB that lets you select and boot different, older OS kernels. Try a few; maybe one will work.

### Another Possible Solution

sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter

note: it took a while for the desktop to load once I got passed the login screen.

### Last resort

Boot into a live environment (that is, use an Ubuntu LiveCD or LiveUSB) and open the file browser. Mount your hard drive ('File System' in the left pane), and backup all important files onto physicial media or the internet.

Then install for a fresh system.

*[NOTE: I'd probably wait a while before moving on to The Last Resort. A grizzled UNIX graybeard may come along with a more palatable solution]*

Comment: Haha.. I would call the 'Last Resort' as poorman's solution :P still, I'll try the commands you posted and will post back

Comment: You can also fresh install 11.10 from LiveCD without formatting. Your /home will be preserved, and installed packages list too (system settings will be lost)

Comment: I spotted one system at my workplace having same problem, so I have tried this stuff on it. I feel @j-johan-edwards was right, `update` said that many packages had troubles downloading. I ran `upgrade` again, and now am waiting for it to finish the process its in

Comment: I ran `update` first, it showed me the errors, that I've attached in the question. I then `upgrade`d the system, after a while, It got done with upgrade, but it still gets stuck at 'checking battery state`

Comment: Hey, I just tried `update` and it asked me to run `sud dpkg --configure -a`. I did so, and later, ran `upgrade` as Johan had suggested, and Voila! I am back into Ubuntu again, with the sexy login screen!
Thanks so much man! :)

Comment: AWesome answer! If I could I would upvote it more :) Indeed, as @SheikhAman, I ran `sudo apt-get update` and somewhere midway I got the error to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update` said there was nothing to do, so reboot, and voila!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after I did Ctrl-Alt-F2,

> sudo apt-get remove nvidia-173

and rebooted, the system started up as intended. I'm not sure why
this worked, and I'm not sure it worked because of removing the
nvidia driver -- but I had seen someone else doing the same thing,
and it was a very easy thing to try.

By the way: In all, Ubuntu is a fantastic piece of software, and I
wouldn't dream of changing it for any another OS. But I'm very,
very disappointed with the new versions of Unity and Gnome 3
(gnome-shell), and I really wish they'd be easier to customize.
Two simple examples: I really don't want to waste screen estate on
the top of my screen, with a menu-bar which is several inches from
the program it's supposed to support, and I'd love to have a way
to easily see which programs are running on my current desktop,
without having to add another panel (this time in the bottom of
the screen) -- but I've found no way to change the standard
behaviour. I didn't have any of these problems before 'upgrading',
and I think it's a pity there seems to be no easy way to revert to
my old settings.

I wish this 'uncustomizability' of both Unity and Gnome 3 had been
pointed out to me be before upgrading, and I've actually decided
to install Kubuntu (inside of 'gubuntu'), just because of it.

Comment: I agree with both of the above. I also am having difficulties in adjusting with the new 'type to search' thing, its difficult to be comfortable with. the Unity 3d is also quite buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Did the upgrade from home over vnc over the weekend. Tried to vnc later and couldnt get back onto my box.

Today I went into work and found that the machine would not boot up. After a while trying to figure it out, thinking that maybe it was a grub problem, i Googled and still didnt find any great solutions.

I then booted up into a previous kernel and finally got to the command prompt. From there i ran

> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

where I ran into the error telling me to

> sudo dpkg --configure -a

after this completed, i rebooted the machine, no GRUB came up, it just booted correctly into 11.10 Gnome Login Screen.

Everything seems to be working perfectly now..