# Upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 crashed

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, upgrade

I am new to ubuntu and linux as a whole.
I had kept my system on **upgrade 11.04 to 11.10** and suddenly the terminal box showed up with some commands and was stuck there.

i tried to reboot but again the terminal shows with set of boot sequences and gets stuck.

Comment: Apart from what do I do now, what is your question? You will need to give a lot more information about what happened. What were the messages? An upgrade to an existing install works much the same as as an update to an existing install. It should not go into a terminal box unless you were asked to re-boot. Were you asked to re-boot? Did you reboot the machine during the upgrade? At what point during the upgrade did this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here this morning.  I had rebooted by the end of a hung up install.  I downgraded to 11.04 and then reupgraded to 11.10 and it worked.

Best thing to prevent major data loss is to have the /home directory on a separate partition...

David

Comment: David, so you suggest i format and reinstall 11.04 and run the upgrade again? That will get 11.10 working?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a CD (download from Internet and burn), I would boot from the CD and format your disk. What I did was make one partition (12 GB) for the Ubuntu system (called "/") and the rest of the disk (aside from a small swap partition) as my /home partition. This allows me, in case of disaster, to format "/" and leave all my personal data in tact.

Comment: is there any alternative to formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [Crash after update to 11.10, from 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65988/crash-after-update-to-11-10-from-11-04). It helped me, and I think it will work for you as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A restoration method suggestion from an inexperienced user:

I installed 11.04 using the Ubuntu windows installer "wubi" so that I could use "Acronis True Image" to restore 11.04 in the event a Ubuntu update or upgrade failure trashed my system.  My system was rendered usless about 15 minutes ago after I attempted to install the 11.10 upgrade. I shut down, booted XP ran Windows Explorer and deleted the C:\wubildr, C:\wubildr.mbr files and the C:\Ubuntu folder.  Then I used Acronis to restore those files and the Ubuntu folder.  Then rebooted.  Ubuntu 11.04 was restored and running in about 6 minutes.  So I don't feel so bad about the attempted upgrade failing.  I will try upgrading again after a couple of weeks and perhaps the bugs will be sorted out by them

I have done this several times after a failed update or upgrade.  It is much less time consuming and less frustrating than trying to rebuild the system from scratch or fix a blown Linux OS.  Perhaps this method might be worth consideration but please remember to  backup your Windows system prior to doing a Ubuntu update or upgrade.

Jim, 
Corvallis, OR