# Ubuntu doesn't boot after 11.10 upgrade from 11.04

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, boot, tty

Had this problem earlier: [Crash after update to 11.10, from 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65988/crash-after-update-to-11-10-from-11-04); ran the solution and had everything updated and upgraded.

I get the following lines after booting with some of the preceding `start`, `stop` an `[OK]` lines as the other topic.

```
* Checking battery state...
[   21.640534] btusb_intr_complete: hci0 urb ffff88011e948480 failed to resubmit (19)
[   21.640690] btusb_bulk_complete: hci0 urb ffff88011e948cc0 failed to resubmit (19)
[   21.640734] btusb_bulk_complete: hci0 urb ffff88011e9480c0 failed to resubmit (19)
```

I run `tty2` and execute `startx` to start the GUI that I'm using right now but Ubuntu won't boot without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the display manager is not loading. Try these commands,

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

If this works, it means lightdm is installed but not configured as default display manager. To set it as default display manager, use this command.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choose lightdm as default display manager. If the above command does not work, try this

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

In case it still doesn't work, try purging lightdm and reinstalling.

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Answer (score -1):

I just entered `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and selected
gdm and EVERYTHING WORKS! again... especially Google-Earth.
(after all else failed...)